# OpenCV, python - is there a way to detect clouds and sun at the same time

Tags: python, computer-vision, detection, opencv

I'm new to python and opencv so I don' really know a lot functions yet, but here is my question

In this picture you can see that my code can detect sun, since sun consists of completely white pixels [0,0,0] I just went thourgh all the pixels and checked which ones are white and it worked pretty good. There is also a little bit of noise but that doesn't affect me so far.
[sun with no clouds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d43QI.jpg)
However when sun gets fully or partially covered by clouds, this is the result:
[sun covered by clouds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWsIG.jpg)

So my question is: is there a way to detect and seperate both the sun and the clouds. I'm using the color of pixels to detect sun, but thats probably not going to work if i want to detect and have my program distinguish between them.

Here is my code:

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

img = cv.imread('sc2.png')
img = cv.resize(img, (900,500), interpolation = cv.INTER_LINEAR)
#gray = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
height, width, channels = img.shape

bela = [255,255,255]
crna = [0,0,0]

for x in range(width):
    for y in range(height):
        pixels_xy = img[y,x]
        if all(pixels_xy == bela):
            img[y,x] = crna

cv.imshow('img',img)
#cv.imshow('gray',gray)
cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Thank you for all the tips!

Comment: is the camera HDR? is its {exposure time * aperture area} constant/fixed? unaltered source pics would be useful (as opposed to screenshots, or anything otherwise altered)

Comment: I'll have to ask for camera specifications since it is not mine. So I'm using a screenshot of a video to process it in opencv, if that helps.